# Scaling custom UIView by CGAffineTransformMakeScale breaks dragging with touchesMoved

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, cgaffinetransform, cgaffinetransformscale

I have prepared and checked into GitHub [a simple test case](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/DragTiles) for dragging custom `UIView`:

[image: app screenshot]

It works well and dragging is implemented in the [Tile.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/DragTiles/DragTiles/Tile.m) as:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint previous = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    self.frame = CGRectOffset(self.frame,
                              (location.x - previous.x),
                              (location.y - previous.y));
}
```

However the tiles are too large for [my actual game](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/Scroll) (and I will have to adjust their scaling once the game board in `UIScrollView` is zoomed anyway):

[image: app screenshot]

So I scale my custom `UIView`s down by calling

```
tile.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.5, .5);
```

The size changes, but the tiles are suddenly dragged "twice as quickly" as needed:

[image: app screenshot]

Probably the `touchesMoved` code (s. above) should be adjusted, but I'm not sure what has been broken there by the `transform` manipulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I have found the solution:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint previous = [touch previousLocationInView:self];

    if (!CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(self.transform)) {
        location = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(location, self.transform);
        previous = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(previous, self.transform);
    }

    self.frame = CGRectOffset(self.frame,
                              (location.x - previous.x),
                              (location.y - previous.y));
}
```